# Resize selected area of image

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image, image-processing

I want to increase / decrease the height of the image for the selected area only (The area between the white lines) as depicted in the image and not the outside of that area.

[image]

This is the same functionality which is performed in the app **Manly - Body Muscle Editor Pro**

How can I achieve that? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've never written code for IOS but I know OpenCV also works in IOS. Here I use the `cv2.resize`.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("1.jpg")

print(img.shape)

h = img.shape[0]
w = img.shape[1]

part_to_resize = img[120:240,:]

old_height = 120 #240-120
new_height = 200

final_result = np.zeros((h-(240-120)+new_height,w,3),dtype='uint8')

final_result[0:119,:] = img[0:119,:]
final_result[120:320,:] =  cv2.resize(part_to_resize, (w, new_height))
final_result[321:h-old_height+new_height,:] = img[241:h,:]

cv2.imshow("final_result", final_result)
cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! Is there any example in iOS Swift/ObjC ? I've successfully configured it in my project but a bit more info like how to do it? Can anyone  help in that?